# PDO fetch returns nothing when trying to use a modular query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, explode

The idea is that I have an array of users from which keys are taken to create a string for pdo to prepare (the index of users). And then binding the user from that array to the corresponding parameters.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `payload` IS NOT NULL
```

I added a parameter to this string with this:

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $sql = $sql." AND `user` LIKE :user".$key;
}
```

Note: I'm just using keys from an array generated with an explode statement on a user defined string. Not 100% sure if the key is safe, but I found no relevant information on this.

The string generated from this with users = `array([0]=>01)` equals:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename`
WHERE `payload` IS NOT NULL
AND `user` LIKE :user0
```

Later I bind the values using this:

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $stmt->bindValue(":user".$key, "\"%".$user."%\"");
}
```

Which means the statement to `execute()` equals:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `payload` IS NOT NULL AND `user` LIKE "%01%"
```

If I execute this statement on phpmyadmin I get 368 results, but this while loop doesn't get executed at all:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // do stuff
}
```

`$db->errorInfo()` returns this `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

---

Edit: Has been resolved.
I didn't need to add quotation marks to the parameter as mysql was searching for the quotation marks my column.

Comment: You don't need to quote parameter values.  Just do `$stmt->bindValue(":user".$key, "%$user%");`.

Comment: you solved your problem?

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this solution:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `payload` IS NOT NULL";

foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $sql .= " AND `user` LIKE ?";
}

$i = 1;
foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $stmt->bindValue($i, "\"%".$user."%\"", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    ++$i;
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem has been resolved. I didn't need to quote the parameter value. With the quotes it meant that mysql was searching for the quotation marks as well in the `user` column.

Comment: @PeterWever  if you consider that my answer help you you can check it as correct

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.